# Cannot make the method retryWhen work(Kotlin, Rx)

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

I invoke `retryNextTweet.onNext()` method but it doesn't make observable retry.
My goal is to get the next item from the local storage. If there are no records in sqlite, then i'll fill the local storage using apiService and retry.

```
private val retryNextTweet: PublishSubject<Any> = PublishSubject.create()

override fun getNextTweet(cacheId: Long, tweetSearchParams: TweetSearchParams): Observable<Tweet> {
    return tweetDao.getNextTweet(cacheId)
            .toObservable()
            .retryWhen {
                it.flatMap { loadTweetsFromApi(tweetSearchParams).subscribe({
                    if(it.isNotEmpty())
                        retryNextTweet.onNext(Any())
                }, {})
                    retryNextTweet }
            }
}

@Dao
interface TweetDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM tweet WHERE cacheId > :cacheId LIMIT 1")
    fun getNextTweet(cacheId: Long): Single<Tweet>
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you have retryWhen there. RetryWhen is for retrying a failed source. Try switchIfEmpty or flatMap if emptiness is an item property.

Comment: Room db throws EmptyResultSetException

Comment: Okay. Try BehaviorSubject instead of PublishSubject. Also check if you really get isNotEmpty true back from the api call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just replaced PublishSubject with a BehaviorSubject and it worked. Thank you akarnokd https://stackoverflow.com/users/61158/akarnokd